# Curl JSON to output only one object

Tags: json, bash, jq

I would like to extract a single values from the output of a json file.

```
curl cli.fyi/8.8.8.8
```

Outputs

```
{
"type": "IP Address",
"data": {
    "organisation": "Google LLC",
    "country": "United States",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "continent": "North America",
    "latitude": "37.751",
    "longitude": "-97.822"
}
}
```

I can run this:

```
curl cli.fyi/8.8.8.8 2>/dev/null | awk -F'"' '$2=="organisation"'
```

and it will output:

```
"organisation": "Google LLC",
```

How can I get only `Google LLC` ?

Comment: If you dont have a parser installed, neither you want to install one, I would rather suggest to use grep with a lazy regex written on perl syntax. That is something like: `command | grep -P regexp`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to parse JSON, your best bet is to use an actual JSON parser rather than trying to do it with `awk` or similar. The [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool is great for this:

```
curl cli.fyi/8.8.8.8 | jq -r .data.organization
```

That would give you the bare string:

```
Google LLC
```

Comment: Great, that works. Just needed to install jq. Used Homebrew : brew install jq